# Rails debug toolbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, Rails programmers, is there any good debugging toolbar for Rails working with current stable ruby/rails releases? What I need is mainly executed queries, maybe some profiling information, I know I can find some of these things in log, but I need toolbar that works with rails4 and ruby1.9.3.

Comment: In addition to RailsPanel, you might be looking for [MiniProfiler](http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler). It can also help tell you where a query comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Chrome, you can try RailsPanel:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/railspanel/gjpfobpafnhjhbajcjgccbbdofdckggg